# How can I change my folder background colour without using any external software

Tags: windows-7

I want to change the background colour of my folders in windows 7. I have seen many ways to do this by downloading programs and running them, but I want to do this without downloading anything, e.g. using the registry. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well this works for me:

> Run regedit and navigate to:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors
>
> Right click on the "colors" key and make a backup (export the reg key).
>
> Then in the right pane scroll down to window - double click and change the value to 200 200 200
>
> Exit registry editor and log off then log back on again. You'll see a background like this:
>
> [image]

Credit: http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/336693-how-change-background-color-folders-windows-7-a.html

Comment: Im old and i use windows NT